# Is it possible to extract coordinates from a static map picture?

Tags: google-maps, maps, arcgis

I was wondering if it were possible to extract coordinates from a static map picture like this:

[image: Map of oil and gas routes]

Is it possible to extract the coordinates of the routes? The only idea I can come up with, other than manually getting them by hand, is by overlaying the map and extracting the exact coordinates that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process that you are looking for is called **georeferencing** in a GIS context.

In order to determine the latitude/longitude coordinates of a point (or series of points in a line), you need to first establish coordinates of other known points. These are *reference points* of known locations (such as a distinctive coastline, or a city). Applying these to the raster image that you have, you can then overlay it on a map in a GIS application and then query other unknown locations on the image (such as the routes) to establish their latitude/longitude.

You could attempt this in a graphics program by looking at the x/y coordinates of the route pixels and compare to a known reference point pixel; however, the math on that is going to be tedious and you also wouldn't account for the map projection. Both of those are taken care of by georeferencing.

I would note that you should consider the results you get, even in a well-referenced GIS, to be approximate. The map deals with a very large spatial area, and the routes cover long distances. But since it dates from 2012 it was presumably *made* in a GIS application and so at least the source data is likely to be accurate :)

Additional resources:

- [Help Page for ArcGIS](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/fundamentals-for-georeferencing-a-raster-dataset.htm) (both overview and instructions)
- [Help Page for QGIS](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/georeferencing_basics.html) (tutorial)